# Create subscription to a group conversation using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I would like to create a subscription to a user's group conversation.
In order to do so, I have an api call to **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions** with the following payload -

```
{
    "changeType": "created, updated",
    "clientState": "something",
    "expirationDateTime": "2022-11-04T13:29:33.988006Z",
    "notificationUrl": "https://some.com",
    "resource": "groups('{id}')/conversations"
}
```

But I am getting this error code (400 status code) -
`Subscription to a group's 'conversations' is not supported with Application-level permissions.`

According to the docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0
I should be able to do so, however, I get that error (using indeed, application permissions, and I cannot use user delegated permissions for my purposes)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), it's not possible to create a subscription for conversation resource with application permissions.

[image]

No workaround right now if you cannot use user delegated permissions.